# Angular material drop event returns wrong index of dragged item and moves wrong item

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, draggable, angular-cdk

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to setup two lists of chips which are draggable between two lists. The two variables availableActivationCountries and availableGroupCountries are filled by filtering another array, as shown below.

```
this.availableActivationCountries = this.brandCountries.filter(c => c.brandAvailable === true).sort((a, b) => (a.country < b.country ? -1 : 1));
this.availableGroupCountries = this.brandCountries.filter(c => c.brandAvailable === false).sort((a, b) => (a.country < b.country ? -1 : 1));
```

When I drag an item from the second list to the list above, a wrong index is returned in the drop event and a totally different item is moved.

If I fill the arrays with fixed data, it works as expected. So it has something to do with the filtering of brandCountries.

Does anyone has an idea on how to solve this?

component.ts

```
  dropCountry(event: CdkDragDrop<ICountry[]>) {
    console.log(event.item.element)
    console.log(event.previousContainer.data)
    //console.log(event.container.data[event.currentIndex].country)
    if (event.previousContainer != event.container) {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data, event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);

      this.availableActivationCountries.sort((a, b) => (a.country < b.country ? -1 : 1));
      this.availableGroupCountries.sort((a, b) => (a.country < b.country ? -1 : 1));

      console.log(this.availableActivationCountries);
    }
  }
```

component.html

```
<div cdkDropListGroup>
  <div cdkDropList [ngClass]="{'emptyDropArea' : availableActivationCountries.length == 0}" cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" (cdkDropListDropped)="dropCountry($event)" [cdkDropListData]="availableActivationCountries">
    <mat-chip-list id="activationCountries">
      <mat-chip cdkDrag selected *ngFor="let country of availableActivationCountries">
        <mat-chip-avatar>
          <img src="https://flagcdn.com/w20/{{country.country.toLowerCase()}}.png" width="20"/>
        </mat-chip-avatar>
        {{ country.country | translate }}
      </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
  </div>
  <!--  <h4>Available countries to add to Group</h4> -->
  <div cdkDropList [ngClass]="{'emptyDropArea' : availableGroupCountries.length == 0}" cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" (cdkDropListDropped)="dropCountry($event)" [cdkDropListData]="availableGroupCountries">
    <mat-chip-list id="availableCountries">
      <mat-chip cdkDrag *ngFor="let country of availableGroupCountries">
        <mat-chip-avatar>
          <img src="https://flagcdn.com/w20/{{country.country.toLowerCase()}}.png" width="20"/>
        </mat-chip-avatar>
        {{ country.country | translate }}
      </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
  </div>
  <h4>Inactive MyAccount countries</h4>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I've tried to remove the filter on brandCountries. This doesn't change a thing. The amount of elements in the array may be the problem.

When the chip are in single line, it works properly.

[image]

It goes wrong from the moment that there are divided across multiple lines.

[image]

Comment: I have found that the wrong index can be used in the "previousIndex" when you drag from a list that has hidden (via CSS or otherwise) items before it in the list.  You cannot just hide elements in the draglist.  They must be removed to make the coordinates line up correctly when dragging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the cdkDropListOrientation attribute solved my problem.